# Java button click

Tags: java, servlets

I have this code below that counts the hits to a page in Netbeans. It works when counting the the page hits. However, I want it to have a button to reset. How do I do this? Any suggestions?

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class PageHitCounter extends HttpServlet{

    private int hitCount;

    public void init()
    {
        // Reset hit counter.
        hitCount = 0;
    }

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException
    {

        response.setContentType("text/html");

        hitCount++;
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        String title = "Total Number of Hits";
        String docType =
        "<!doctype html public \"-//w3c//dtd html 4.0 " +
        "transitional//en\">\n";
        out.println(docType +
        "<html>\n" +
        "<head><title>" + title + "</title></head>\n" +
        "<body bgcolor=\"#d8d8d8\">\n" +
        "<h1 align=\"center\">" + title + "</h1>\n" +
        "<h2 align=\"center\">" + hitCount + "</h2>\n" +
        "</body></html>");

    }
    public void destroy()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want hits per this user, use session. If you want overall hits from all users, use a database.

Comment: All this is being done in netbeans. He wants a servlet to do this.

Comment: You still have to decide if you want the servlet to put the hit counter in session or a database.

Answer (score 2):

This does not seem correct to me, because there's no guarantee the next request will be assigned to the same servlet instance. Instead, you should store the hitCount variable in a HttpSession object.

that said, you need a way to know if your request is to increment or reset the counter. I suggest adding a GET parameter in your request, so your doGet() method can know what command is to be done.

Comment: how would I modify the code that I have into something that would work?